# What other ways to say 'mess place'?

Tags: word-usage, word-request

i want to know how to put 'messy place'in other ways. For example, when you go to the airport or restaurant looks dirty and is disarranged what can you say? i know these two what a mess/ it is messy.

Answer (score 1):

One of the most common ways to say that a place looks all dirty would, of course, be:

> This place is a dump!

I don't think that it's at all possible to escape the word *dump* when describing places that look messy (a dump is a site for depositing garbage). And I think there is no other word in English that's nearly as common as this one. However, the next one in order, which in terms of its meaning and usage comes very close to the previous one, would probably be the word *mess*:

> The place is a mess!

Also, consider the word *pigsty* which is almost identical in its use to the two previous ones:

> This place is a pigsty!

Let's wait and see what other people will come up with.